# What is this breadboard that can be soldered on a PCB

Tags: pcb, breadboard

Very simple question. What is the part number of this small bread board on [this board](http://store.digilentinc.com/anvyl-spartan-6-fpga-trainer-board/).
[image]

There are two breadboards on it. The smaller one actually is **soldered** on the PCB and it is **connected** to IOs of an FPGA. I searched on Mouser for a long time to find this kind of component, but I failed. Could anybody tell me what this would be called such that I could find a supplier?

Comment: I've edited your question so that it's no longer a shopping question. (Also added the board image so people don't need to follow the link.) this should make the question acceptable.

Comment: As far as I know, most breadboards expose the pins if the backing is removed.  Maybe it is just any normal breadboard.

Comment: http://hobbycomponents.com/prototyping/658-2x4-pcb-mounted-mini-breadboard

Answer (score -6):

The small one is to connect electronic components in the IO's it has on. That's why it's soldered. You can program the components connected to those pins. The other breadboard is for prototyping. You can wire and connect any sort of electronics you want (sensors, servos, resistors, potentiometers etc.) and then use the IO's of the small breadboard to communicate with them (get sensors' data or "tell" a servo to rotate).

Comment: I think you need to read the question again before answering.